# How to proceed extracting data on a gps localizer?

Tags: php, pdo

I got these errors while submitting my form. What can be the problem? Thanks

1) ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined'

2) PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in

This is the code

```
if (!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
require 'dbconnection.php';
require 'functions.php';
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE (login = :pseudo) AND activated != NULL');
$req->execute(['login' => $_POST['pseudo']]);
$user = $req->fetch();

if (password_verify($_POST['pass'], $user->password)) {
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['auth'] = $user;
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
}else{
  $_SESSION['flash']['danger'] = 'Login ou mot de passe incorrecte';
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change  execute statement to

```
$req->execute([':pseudo' => $_POST['pseudo']]);
```

Because you create placeholder for `pseudo` not `login`

and use  `IS NOT NULL` to check NULL

```
$req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE (login = :pseudo) AND activated IS NOT NULL');
$req->execute([':pseudo' => $_POST['pseudo']]);
```

Comment: Have you check the solution??

Comment: yes but I got this time _Fatal error: Cannot redeclare debug() (previously declared in C:\wamp64\www\wintrack\functions.php:3) in C:\wamp64\www\wintrack\functions.php on line 5_

Comment: have you create function having name `debug()`??

Comment: And this ** Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\wintrack\connexion.php on line 10**

Comment: `<?php

 function debug($variable){
  echo '<pre>'.print_r($variable, true).'</pre>';
 }

Comment: Okk check it to some other name something `debug_data()` and check

Comment: Thanks @Saty It works very fine now but the error _Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\wintrack\connexion.php on line 10_ still occurs

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
  if (!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['pseudo']) && !empty($_POST['pass'])) {
    require 'dbconnection.php';
    //require 'functions.php';
    $req = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM utilisateurs WHERE (login = :pseudo) AND activated IS NOT NULL');
    $req->execute([':pseudo' => $_POST['pseudo']]);
    $user = $req->fetch();



 if (password_verify($_POST['pass'], $user->password)) {
      session_start();
      $_SESSION['auth'] = $user;
      header('Location: index.php');
      exit();
    }else{
      $_SESSION['flash']['danger'] = 'Login ou mot de passe incorrecte';
    }

 }
```